# Having a lot of trouble understanding Semaphores

Tags: .net, multithreading, c++-cli, semaphore

Here is a basic code with my goal to print out AAABBCAAABBC....and so on.

1. What is the point/meaning of the two arguments in the Semaphore(int, int)?
2. Can someone explain why I am getting the output BBAAABBC and then it ends?

Overall I am really struggling to see a pattern when I make changes to my code and observe the output.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::Threading;

    ref class PrintTasks
    {
    private:
        static Semaphore ^canPrintA = gcnew Semaphore(0,3);
        static Semaphore ^canPrintB = gcnew Semaphore(2,2);
        //static Semaphore ^canPrintC = gcnew Semaphore(0,1);
        static Semaphore ^Idle = gcnew Semaphore(0,3);


    public: static bool runFlag = true;

    public:
        void PrintA(Object^ name) {
            while (runFlag) {
                canPrintA->WaitOne();
                Console::Write("{0}\n", "A");
                Idle->Release();
            }
        }

        void PrintB(Object^ name) {
            while (runFlag) {
                canPrintB->WaitOne();
                Console::Write("{0}\n", "B");
                Idle->Release();
            }
        }

        void PrintC(Object^ name) {
            while (runFlag) {
                Idle->WaitOne();
                Idle->WaitOne();
                                    Console::Write("{0}\n", "C");
                canPrintA->Release(3);
                Idle->WaitOne();
                Idle->WaitOne();
                Idle->WaitOne();
                canPrintB->Release(2);
                //Console::Write("{0}\n", "C");



            }
        }

    };

    int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
    {

        PrintTasks ^tasks = gcnew PrintTasks();

        // First Method
        Thread ^thread1 = gcnew Thread ( gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart( tasks, &PrintTasks::PrintA ) );
        Thread ^thread2 = gcnew Thread ( gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart( tasks, &PrintTasks::PrintB ) );
        Thread ^thread3 = gcnew Thread ( gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart( tasks, &PrintTasks::PrintC ) );

        thread1->Start("printA");
        thread2->Start("printB");
        thread3->Start("printC");

        Thread::Sleep(50);

        PrintTasks::runFlag=false;

        thread3->Abort();
        thread2->Abort();
        thread1->Abort();

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: 1) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx : "Initializes a new instance of the Semaphore class, specifying the maximum number of concurrent entries and optionally reserving some entries."

Comment: Ok...but what does setting it as Semaphore(2,2) accomplish?

Comment: Didn´t you understand or didn´t you read it at all? If 1: Do you know what Semaphores are used for?

Comment: You cannot use one Semaphore to order 3 threads, it requires three of them.  Allowing one thread to release another.  You'd normally use three AutoResetEvents instead.  The entire approach is wrong to begin with, if you want ABC to appear in order then just use *one* thread that prints A, then B, then C.  There is no point in having more threads waiting around to get their turn, that's just wasteful and slow.

Comment: I read over it but I am still confused.

Comment: @HansPassant I have been using a sample code that accomplishes a similar task of TTTPP repeated. It uses nearly the same layout as what I devised.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the point/meaning of the two arguments in the Semaphore(int,int)?

There are two main ways in which Semaphores are useful.

### Limited resources

Semaphores can be used in order to restrict access to a limited resource. To achieve this, set the maximum counter to the desired limit, and the initial count to zero. Each thread allocating a resource has to `WaitForSingleObject()` before to get a free semaphore "slot". If there are no more free slots, the wait will block until one thread releases a semaphore handle, making room for the next waiting thread. For this use case, the semaphore usage could be described best as a *multi-mutex*.

### Multiple events

The other typical use case is the ability to signal the occurrence of *multiple events*, for example with thread pools. Initialize both the semaphore maximum and the current count with MAXINT, or some other adequately high value. The value itself isn't that important (the higher the better), it must just be high enough to cover all possible scenarios. Then have all worker threads waiting on your semaphore. Since there are no free handles yet, all worker threads will block waiting.

Now, whenever some task comes in that should be handled by our thread pool, this event is signaled by releasing one or more handles via `ReleaseSemaphore()`, waking up exactly that amount of threads from the pool. These threads will now perform their desired work, e.g. picking up and processing a work task from somewhere.

Once the thread finishes his work, he starts again waiting on the semaphore. If there are any remaining events (because the number of signaled events exceeds the number of threads available), the thread will immediately start handling the next package. Otherwise the thread will simply fall asleep again, waiting for new events.

Comment: It seems like the second use is what I am looking to use.